# Help! My wxMac app does not accept mouse or keyboard input

Tags: macos, wxwidgets

I have followed the wxWidgets "hello world" tutorial here: http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/hello.htm

Everything seems fine, the program compiles and starts, but the app is totally unresponsive. I can't click the window to front or move it. What could be wrong?

I am using wxMac on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a bundle for Carbon and Cocoa apps on OS X.

If your binary is named "foo" then this works for testing purposes (don't ship like this):

```
 mkdir -p foo.app/Contents/MacOS
 mv foo foo.app/Contents/MacOS
```

When you get things working you can eventually tweak your build system to make the bundle before the final link step and pass `-o foo.app/Contents/MacOS/foo` to the linker rather than plain `-o foo`.

For a Makefile that automates this, see [the wxWidgets web forum](http://wxforum.shadonet.com/viewtopic.php?p=30345#30345).